# How do I enable HTTPS for the embedded tomcat in Denodo?

Tags: tomcat, https, data-virtualization, denodo

I'd like to enable https for all my incoming web requests to Denodo using a self-signed certificate.  How do I do this?

(Denodo comes installed with an embedded JRE and Tomcat)

*(I'm posting this question and including the answer in hopes that someone else finds it useful)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Enabling HTTPS with a self-signed cert consists of a few steps:

1. Create a key-pair and add it to a keystore
2. Extract a certificate from your key-pair in your keystore
3. Add your certificate to the embedded JRE cacerts file
4. Configure the Denodo Tomcat to use your keystore and the default cacerts file

NOTE: If you want to use your own truststore (instead of the built-in cacerts), you can do that, your steps will be slightly different but the general idea is the same.

NOTE 2: If you want to use a signed-certificate the same *rule* applies... you're steps will be slightly different but the general idea is the same... (instead of importing your cert into the cacerts file you'll need to generate a certificate signing request and get that signed).

### Step 1: Create a Key-Pair and add it to a new keystore

On your denodo server run the following:

```
$ /lclapps/denodo/jre/bin/keytool -genkey -alias nvdrdenodo2 -keyalg RSA -keystore 

~/command_line.keystore`enter code here`
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  first_last
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  Technology
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  My OU
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  San Francisco
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  CA
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  US
Is CN=first_last, OU=Technology, O=My OU, L=San Francisco, ST=CA, C=US correct?
  [no]:  yes
Enter key password for <nvdrdenodo2>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

You **must** make sure the key-pair password is the same as the keystore password.  Remember the password :-)

### Step 2: Extract your key as a certificate in PEM format

Run the following command and be sure to include the password you used in step 1.

```
/lclapps/denodo/jre/bin/keytool -exportcert -alias nvdrdenodo2 -keystore ~/command_line.keystore -storepass MyPassword -rfc -file ~/nvdrdenodo2.cer
```

### Step 3: Import your .cer file into the embedded JRE's cacerts file

```
/lclapps/denodo/jre/bin/keytool -import -alias nvdrdenodo2 -keystore /lclapps/denodo/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file ~/nvdrdenodo2.cer
Enter keystore password:
Owner: CN=first_last, OU=Technology, O=My OU, L=San Francisco, ST=CA, C=US
Issuer: CN=first_last, OU=Technology, O=My OU, L=San Francisco, ST=CA, C=US
Serial number: 54341d2a
Valid from: Tue Oct 07 11:04:42 MDT 2014 until: Mon Jan 05 10:04:42 MST 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  3A:9F:37:16:3F:17:9B:BF:3A:95:CE:2C:ED:8A:FF:22
         SHA1: 6A:9E:75:68:7A:33:2C:F9:E3:11:01:CC:2E:7B:00:4C:B8:D2:E6:AF
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
Certificate stored in file </home/user_account/nvdrdenodo2.cer>
```

### Step 4: Update your $DENODO_HOME/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/tomcat.properties file

We now configure tomcat to utilize our keystore and leave the truststore lines commented out since it will use the embedded JRE cacerts file by default.

```
vi /lclapps/denodo/resources/apache-tomcat/conf/tomcat.properties

com.denodo.tomcat.home=/lclapps/denodo-5.0/resources/apache-tomcat
com.denodo.tomcat.http.port=9090
com.denodo.tomcat.shutdown.port=9099
com.denodo.tomcat.jmx.port=9098
com.denodo.tomcat.engine.name=DenodoPlatform-5.0
com.denodo.tomcat.export.dirname=export
com.denodo.tomcat.http.log=true
com.denodo.tomcat.https.enable=true
com.denodo.tomcat.https.port=9443
com.denodo.security.ssl.enabled=true
com.denodo.security.ssl.keyStore=/home/user_account/command_line.keystore
com.denodo.security.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
#com.denodo.security.ssl.trustStore=
#com.denodo.security.ssl.trustStorePassword=
java.env.DENODO_OPTS_START=-Xmx2056m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=256m
```

### Restart and Test

Restart Denodo, and go to `https://yourserver:9443/denodo-restfulws/admin` and see if it works (or go to any url of a published web service).  You should get a certificate error:

[image: Cert error]

Add the exception and you are now accessing Denodo Tomcat over HTTPS with your own cert!